# OAuth - Get Twitter access token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to get a Twitter access token with OAuth 2.0? I came along [this thread](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/token) but I don't understand it. Do they support OAuth 2.0 or are they still using OAuth 1.0A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) page:

> Twitter offers applications the ability to issue authenticated
>   requests on behalf of the application itself (as opposed to on behalf
>   of a specific user). Twitter's implementation is based on the Client
>   Credentials Grant flow of the OAuth 2 specification. Note that OAuth
>   1.0a is still required to issue requests on behalf of users.

Therefore, no they do not fully support OAuth 2.

Comment: `Note that OAuth 1.0a is still required to issue requests on behalf of users` What kind of requests are they meaning? I would like to let users post to their feed through my app. Do I need to use OAuth 1.0A for this?

Comment: Yes in order for your app to post tweets, or perform any other action on behalf of a user, you will need to use OAuth 1.0a.